# vba: lbound error on dates array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a "Datevarie" dynamic matrix which contains many dates.

At some point in the routine I have to extract from DateVarie the lowest value.

The problem is that when I use the Lbound function, I always return the value 1 instead of the date (for example "01/01/2018").

I think the data in the array is entered correctly as I debugged it step by step several times.

How can I resolve without having to report data on a sheet and order them? Do I have to use FOR ... NEXT? The dates can be 2-3 but also several tens

```
Type interventi
...
data as date
...

public Intervento as interventi
public rs1 as adodb.recordset    
    ...
Sub TheSubWithProblem(...)
...
dim Datevarie() as date
..
redim preserve etc..
DateVarie(k)=format(RS1!DataI,"dd/mm/yyyy") '<<<< correct
...

Intervento.data=lbound(datevarie)  '<<<< always return 1
...
```

Comment: Can you make some [mcve]?

Comment: Sub test()
Dim datevarie(2) As Date
datevarie(1) = DateValue("01/01/2000")
datevarie(2) = DateValue("02/01/2000")
Debug.Print LBound(datevarie)
End Sub.... results "0"

Comment: If you want the date instead of the index, try datevarie(lbound(datevarie)).

Comment: @MassimoGriffani that results 0 because the `LBound` of `datevarie` is `datevarie(0)`.

Comment: @MassimoGriffani Are you looking for the date value in the first position of the array, or the earliest date value anywhere in the array?

Comment: The Earliest date

Comment: `LBound` gives the smallest index used in the array while `UBound` gives the largest index. Unless your array is sorted from earliest to latest date, you probably don't want or need `LBound`

Comment: I see what you mean now - you're returning the *index* but not the value - if you want that  value, try `Debug.Print datevarie(LBound(datevarie))`

Comment: You're right @dwirony. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that when I use the Lbound function, I always return the value 1 instead of the date (for example "01/01/2018").

`LBOUND` and `UBOUND` functions return the lower- and upper *bounds* of the array, not the lowest and highest *values* within the array.

Arrays in VBA are base-0 by default, so an initialized array should typically have `LBound` of 0.

If you want to get the lowest or highest value, then you need to implement your own algorithm to do so (e.g., a for/next loop), or if this is a single-dimensional array we can potentially [make use of an `ArrayList` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) which has (among other things) a `Sort` method:

```
Set d = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim dateVarie As Variant
Dim i As Long, m As Long, day As Long

For i = 1 To 100
    m = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 12)
    day = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 30)
    d.Add (DateValue(DateSerial(2018, m, day)))
Next

'Preserve your un-sorted array, if needed:
ReDim dateVarie(d.Count - 1)
dateVarie = d.ToArray()

Msgbox "The first value is: " & dateVarie(0)

d.Sort  ' Sorts the arraylist:

MsgBox "The lowest value is: " & (d(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays start at 0. This is why the below returns 0:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim datevarie(2) As Date
    Debug.Print LBound(datevarie)

End Sub
```

And it does not matter, whether you put values in the array or not.
If you want an array to start at 1, in VBA write `Option Base 1` and make sure that noone sees the code, because you may have problems with your colleagues/peers:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub TestMe()

    Dim datevarie(2) As Date
    Debug.Print LBound(datevarie)

End Sub
```